# Getting a instance of a class

Tags: java, class, instance

I'm wondering if someone could tell me how to get instance from a class. 
Here is my code so far, I saw this from another post but I keep getting a `NullPointerException`

**This is my Main class.**

```
public class Main {

private String name;
private static Main instance;
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Test.sayMyName();
}

public Main(){
    instance = this;
}

public static Main getInstance(){
    return instance;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return this.name;
}
}
```

**And this is my other class.**

```
public class Test { 
public static void sayMyName(){
    Main.getInstance().setName("Hi im John");
    System.out.println(Main.getInstance().getName());
}   
}
```

I'm getting the error at `"Main.getInstance().setName("Hi im John");"`

Comment: You're not calling `new Main()` anywhere...

Comment: Are you trying to implement the [Singleton Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_Pattern)? If not, a normal constructor seems fine to me.

Answer (score 3):

Change the following to lazy initialization

```
public Main(){
    //instance = this;
}

public static Main getInstance(){
    if(instance == null){
          instance = new Main();

    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: @user2992247 you may take a look at the singleton pattern

Answer (score 2):

note that you only set the value of instance inside the constructor, which is never called. Java has a nice trick which allows you to run a block of code once per class (statically). There are other ways to do this (read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2003/jw-0425-designpatterns.html)), but this is as good as any in my opinion.

```
public class Main{
    // member variables
    ...
    // functions like Main(), getInstance(), etc here
    ...
    // static initialization
    static{
        Main.instance = new Main();
    }
}
```

Also, if you want to enforce that the users of `Main` can *only* use that one instance, you can make the constructor `private`. This way they can only access `getInstance`.

Comment: Oh i see so like `private Main() {}` ?

Comment: yes exactly. `private Main() {}` means that no class other than `Main` itself can create it. For extra fanciness, you can make it `protected` if you want sub-singleton-classes. But that's weird and you should avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The static member, instance, is set only in the constructor for class Main.  There is nowhere in your code where you are invoking that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
public class Main {

   private String name;
   private static Main instance;
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test.sayMyName();
   }

   public Main(){

   }

   public static Main getInstance(){
if (instance == null) {
   instance = new Main();
} ;
return instance;
   }

   public void setName(String name){
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getName(){
return this.name;
   }
   }
```